# Tell TypeScript that class has static and instance methods

Tags: typescript

```
class A {
    static hasThisMethod: (any) => any
    hasThisMethodToo: (r : any) => any
}
```

Is it possible to tell TypeScript "trust me, at runtime my class will have this static and this instance method?"

I don't want to extend and abstract class since that will actually place empty versions of those methods in there - I just want to tell TS "trust me, these methods exist at runtime" in some sort of automated way so I don't have to type them out every time, like I did above.

Comment: What do you mean by "every time"? If you define one TypeScript class, and you want that class to have a static method and an instance method, then define them in that class.

Comment: @JBNizet - I mean there will be many such classes that always have this instance and static method - is there a convenient way to annotate it as such with TS?

Comment: Are you looking for `implements`? However, this will not support static methods. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13462.

Comment: Right - implements would be ideal if it supported static methods :(

Comment: So, you actually want to make TypeScript force you to add a static method to a class, right? I don't think that's possible (and am not sure what the point would be, since static methods are not called polymorphically).

Comment: @JBNizet not quite - I'm just looking for a more ergonomic way to tell TS that this static method (and others) will exist at runtime, so the compiler does not yell at me when I try to use them.

Comment: @AdamRackis: I haven't tried to handle this for static methods yet, but I answered it (2 years after you asked it) below, and use this trick for doing something similar: Tell the compiler that "trust me", all of the following methods are going to be implemented, but not here. (In my case, it's easier because I have another class/interface definition already that lists all of the methods I add at runtime. )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like the following?

```
interface A {
  hasThisMethod: (arg: any) => any;
  new(...args: any[]): { hasThisMethodToo: (r: any) => any };
}

class AImpl {
  static hasThisMethod: (arg: any) => any;
  hasThisMethodToo: (r : any) => any;
}

const a: A = AImpl; // this line compiles successfully
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that's a lot closer, but I'd need the class to implement the interface A, and I'm having a lot of difficulty getting TS to be happy with it.  If AImpl would be able to implement A, and not generate compile errors when A.staticMethod() was called, that'd be perfect

Comment: That is not possible. I think there is probably a good alternative that solves your problem. Could you tell your use case in more detail?

Comment: I have a decorator that adds static and instance methods to a class, but TypeScript doesn't yet know how to understand that decorators can mutate classes (there's a GH issue about it somewhere).  I just want a convenient way to "mark" a class to say "these methods exist - don't yell at me when I try to use them"

Comment: You mean [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881), right? As discussed by some people in that issue, the current workaround would be to use functions instead of decorators. My answer is not appropriate as TypeScript does not raise a compilation error even if your decorator does not really mutate a class as declared.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore static methods for a moment, but yes, you can use Interface merging to tell Typescript to trust you about methods that are implemented at runtime.

```
class MyClass{
    public foo(): number{
        return 1;
    }
}

interface ISomeMethodsYouWantToDeclareYouHaveAtRuntime{
    methodDeclaredInInterface(): string;
}

class SomeOtherActualClass{
    public methodDeclaredInAnotherClass(): string{
        return "hello";
    }
}


// Use declaration merging to tell TS that the MyClass class implements the ISomeEmberClass
interface MyClass extends ISomeMethodsYouWantToDeclareYouHaveAtRuntime{
}

// You can also use declaration merging with another class to say that your class will implement the same methods at runtime
interface MyClass extends SomeOtherActualClass{
}

let instance = new MyClass();

// Allowed
instance.foo();
// Also allowed: (yay!)
instance.methodDeclaredInInterface();
// Also allowed!
instance.methodDeclaredInAnotherClass();
```

[Typescript Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=1#code/FAYwNghgzlAECyBPAwpGBvYtuwA4FcAjMASxFgDMB7KgCgEoAuWAO3wFtCBTAJ0xwGweXAC74eLWAEYA3FhwBfYEuAkWI3hQggusAJIBlKuy7xRACyoATKAE0q%20AOoR1AFSoARLuAjD7%20AAkIADcuAEERACV8dRITfhwTEUsrLx9hKz0WLI0eLR0GZigRHjUAczkVHxhYIxMAeWTeMJAxCDBUaCgE7AJiMlgklLTIDKywliomnk6YQthi0pYynsFhMQlYACJzLjAwKi25ASUVYAB6c9gAVShdK29RiBESKkkTHjLy2BEqH72wLBXAYfuZnqDdEhZnBqnA4rgwFwTOo4E19HUuABRTi8aGqdSabSQlBoOBcAAeGhYNnRxlMFmsdgczjcnkevi4-iCoQi0Vi8WUwAuV38sBALlg7Sgf3wd1gD3Sz1e714X2WsAA7iRkpLJtMxaSfn8oBBEKDwYgHDwDV1NSR9rB4YjkSIIQsICZBgyaeCeDEXiZ8bl8sTobAKVSaRjGrseC02h1SZgVIjXWpii4dLAALysLgahAkroMOTC2BhfZUDVcKz4jMsHQAOmodHocku5bA0sllerVmYtEQpoAhPQ6yJM1xG0NrCMOZlsgS8kSS2WK932gc%208Px5Pp9652MWBMprHoaugA)

[Declaration Merging in the Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)